# Flutter SQLite Database enforcing strict data types

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, strict

Traditionally sqlite allowed any data type to be submitted to any field in a database table for example you could submit an INTEGER to a TEXT field. However strict table data types are now officially supported since [sqlite 3.37.0](https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html) for example if you create a strict table you can not submit an INTEGER to a TEXT field.

The flutter [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) package keeps throwing an error not recognizing the STRICT operand.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(field_one INTEGER, field_two TEXT) STRICT;
```

*Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(near "STRICT": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)*

Has anyone been able to enforce strict data types when creating a sqlite table in flutter using the [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) package ?

EDIT---

It would appear that flutter sqflite package uses whatever sqlite version is pre installed on the android/ios device. Flutter sqflite package does not ship/bundle any additional sqlite library so the device is running an old version of sqlite that does not support STRICT data types.

@Pavel provided a method to install the latest version of sqlite on the android/ios device. Using that code as shown below it does indeed  install the latest version of sqlite however it still does not allow you to create a STRICT database table. When you execute the code it created a malformed database table that is corrupted.

```
import 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart';
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';

  sqfliteFfiInit();

  
  var db = await databaseFactoryFfi.openDatabase(inMemoryDatabasePath);

  await db.execute('''
  CREATE TABLE Product (
      field_one INTEGER,
      field_two TEXT
  ) STRICT
  ''');
```

Comment: Did you check the version of SQLite you are using?

Comment: I am not using sqlite directly, I am using the most recent flutter package sqflite 2.0.1

Comment: Execute the query: `select sqlite_version();` and check the return value.

Comment: you can't enter a raw select command into flutter package sqflite 2.0.1

Comment: [You can](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite#raw-sql-queries), use [rawQuery](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite_common/latest/sqlite_api/DatabaseExecutor/rawQuery.html) method

Comment: ok thanks, have not heard of that method before

Comment: oh this is bad, the most recent flutter sqflite 2.0.1 package is using a version of sqlite published several years ago

Answer (score 2):

- Check sqlite version

```dart
db.rawQuery('select sqlite_version();').then(print);
```

This will print the version of sqlite provided by system, e.g

```
[{sqlite_version(): 3.22.0}]
```

- Bundle latest sqlite version within your app

```yaml
sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.5.2 # sqlite 3.37.0
```

- Tell sqflite to use it:

```yaml
sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.1.0 # for sqflite config
```

```dart
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  sqfliteFfiInit();
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  runApp(...);
}
```

Now `select sqlite_version();` will return `3.37.0` and new syntax will work

Comment: Thank you for this, it would appear that sqflite package uses the available SQLite version on the platform. It does not ship/bundle any additional SQLite library. Your above proposal does update sqlite to the latest version but the databaseFactory class does not support the STRICT data types as when I try to add the strict operand it creates a malformed database schema.